# Do I really need Carbon monoxide detector

Tags: gas, smoke-detectors, gas-burner, carbon-monoxide, gasleak

My house has a gas hob other than that I don't have any other appliances which burns off fossil fuel.

I have other heavy appliances like washing machine ,Electric OTG Microwave oven, Fridge,Toaster ,Electric water heater for bathroom, AC(R32 refrigerant) and an inverter but these won't produce carbon monoxide anyways.

So do I really need to buy an carbon monoxide detector ? I mean like if the flame cooler changes from light blue to brownish I'd know that carbon monoxide is being produced may be due less ventilation(oxygen) or low levels of gas(LPG).

May be I should be investing on Gas detector which can detect the leakage of any gas like R32  or LPG from gas cylinder. I know I might be able to find LPG gas detector. But is there any detector that can detect R32 gas leak from AC ?

Any advices are highly welcome

Comment: your answer is in the question, Is your life worth the cost of the detector?

Comment: It is insurance.  You never need or want it till 5 minutes after it is too late.  CO gas is odourless and colourless, so the only time you notice is just before you pass out for the last time.

Comment: Do I really need fire insurance, car insurance?  You make the choice.

Comment: `My house has a gas hob` so, you clearly need a CO detector. Or you can die just like the old days before there were such things, as you wish, suject to possibly breaking local laws, if applicable, but you'll be dead, so...

Comment: I hadn't heard of R32, which is flammable unlike Freon. Here's a detector : https://www.alviautomation.com/refrigerants-gas-leak-detectors-r32/ - As for the stove, not really, until your try to heat your house with it like an idiot (so, yes; I don't put my job on the line hoping people won't be idiots... that's my job). But there's no reason not to get a (combination CO and) explosive gas detector which you should have, definitely, but I'm not sure it can detect R32, so you need both.

Comment: AC not being dangerous anymore, after stopping using ammonia had a good run. *Sad face.*

Comment: Read this and decide for yourself. https://www.abe.iastate.edu/extension-and-outreach/carbon-monoxide-concentrations-table-aen-172/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I'd get a combination CO/flammable gas detector if I were in your shoes

Given that you have a gas combustion appliance (hob) that's probably *more* vulnerable to inadvertent leaks and malfunctions/misoperation than a fixed appliance (like a water heater or a furnace), I would recommend a combination CO/flammable gas detector -- I have a [Kidde KN-COEG](https://www.kidde.com/home-safety/en/us/products/fire-safety/co-alarms/kn-coeg-3/) in my house, although you'll need to look around for something suitable for your 230V mains as the KN-COEG is a 120V unit.

Comment: We have 3 phase residential electrical connection.

Comment: @CuriousMan -- what line-to-neutral voltage does your house run at?

Comment: If you leave the windows and doors open 24/7 then you will not need the CO detector. The end result is you will probably burn the cost of the detector every few days in heating or cooling bills with everything open. To live the most inexpensive solution is to install the CO detector.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - 230 volt

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need a CO detector.

This is cheap insurance against an odorless gas that will kill you.

Where I live, it’s a code requirement.

Also where I live, you can get one for $30, and it lasts 10 years. $3 a year.

Comment: About thirty years ago a decent size family died because of CO.  A year or two after the province made it a law that every house as a CO detector.  Did not wait for code to change.